# Alert crash before clicking the button EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, exc-bad-access

I need to make warning alert which will do the action before clicking "OK", the default UIAlert crashes before clicking without any errors, so I tried to use SIAlert, but it crashes too, the err is EXC_BAD_ACCESS... How to fix it? help me please? Xcode 6.1.1

```
- (IBAction)share:(id)sender {

SIAlertView *alertView = [[SIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Post to VK wall?" andMessage:@"Do u want 2 post VK?"];


[alertView addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"
                         type:SIAlertViewButtonTypeCancel
                      handler:^(SIAlertView *alertView) {
                          NSLog(@"Button3 Clicked");
                      }];
[alertView addButtonWithTitle:@"CANCEL"
                         type:SIAlertViewButtonTypeDestructive
                      handler:^(SIAlertView *alertView) {
                          NSLog(@"Button2 Clicked");
                      }];

alertView.willShowHandler = ^(SIAlertView *alertView) {
    NSLog(@"%@, willShowHandler", alertView);
};
alertView.didShowHandler = ^(SIAlertView *alertView) {
    NSLog(@"%@, didShowHandler", alertView);
};
alertView.willDismissHandler = ^(SIAlertView *alertView) {
    NSLog(@"%@, willDismissHandler", alertView);
};
alertView.didDismissHandler = ^(SIAlertView *alertView) {
    NSLog(@"%@, didDismissHandler", alertView);
};

[alertView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

alertView.title = @"Postin VK";}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwn9Y.png - image og err

Comment: See http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `alertView` is being released at the end of the method, and that's why you get the exception.

You should keep a strong reference to it in your class. Something like this:

```
@implementation MyClass {
    SIAlertView *_alertView;
}

- (IBAction)share:(id)sender {
    _alertView = [[SIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Post to VK wall?" andMessage:@"Do u want 2 post VK?"];
    ...
}

@end
```

Comment: could you give me the detailed instruction? where and what should I change?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
[alertView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

with this:

```
[alertView show];
```

I think it's not finding the @selector(show)

Comment: Those two lines of code are equivalent if run from the main thread.

Comment: Then the error is coming from somewhere else in your code.